# What software is needed to create interactive illustration over a video, within an internet browser?

Tags: video, media, interactive

Here is the project I want to do:

Film a technology project and create an interactive layer over the video, at certain segments, to explain the science involved.  Lets say biofuels, for the sake of simplicity.
The footage would seamlessly integrate, at certain frame-pauses, into a layer that is an technical illustration of the content within the video frame.

Imagine video footage of an interview with a project manager.  The project manager gestures his hand towards a barrel of a fermenting solution that will later become biofuel.  The purpose of the project is to delve into the processes happening within the fermenting solution. So, after the person's interview, they gesture towards the next step in the process: to analyze what is happening during fermentation.  The video frame pans over to a barrel of solution.  PAUSE VIDEO FRAME.  Now, an illustration layer descends, and it zooms into the image in the video frame: a barrel within a warehouse.  Zooming in, the illustration shows illustrated molecules of cellulose being digested by bacteria.  Besides just an illustration, I would like this realistic diagram to be interactive:  the viewer can stir the barrel, or turn up a heating element, to see if it makes the process go faster.

What technology would be needed to produce this interactive technical illustration layer, so that it can be viewed from an internet browser?

I am trying to figure out if I would need to hire a programmer in:
- Flash / Actionscript/ C++ / JibLibFlash
- WebGL,
- Javascript (PhysJL, Threejs)
- Something else...

Thank you for any assistance!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do: Make 2 videos, one before the pause and one after the pause. Make them 2 overlapping DIV's using z-index. Run them with Flash, and autodetect with Javascript that on the first Media's end it changes the opacity of a hidden `<div>` with opacity of zero. Inside this `<div>` you can use CSS3 / HTML5 animations to show whatever animations you need. After the end use something like

`box.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', 
    function( event ) { alert( "Finished transition!" ); }, false );` to initiate the next half of the video. Of course the `z-index` changes to have the most recent one top. Simple!

Comment: you might be able to call the video from MYSQL, too, but I'm not sure how well it stores video...

Comment: Thanks a ton for your feedback, it is very valuable guidance which I greatly appreciate.  I see from your activity that you know what you're talking about, and so I will explore this as an option.